# Fetching/Cashing Data From UIWebView

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I was wondering if there is anyway to get what is being displayed in UIWebView. e.g; you have opened bbc.co.uk in UIWebView and you wanted to save all the content of that page, Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Webkit on iPhone uses the standard `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]` for caching.  If that is the case, you can implement your own cache or query the cache for existing items.  Try:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:myRequest];
```

Implementing your own cache is a more reliable solution, because the system cache may choose not to cache anything.